# How to calculate the mod of large exponents?

Tags: modulo, exponent, largenumber, computation

For example I want to calculate (reasonably efficiently)

2^1000003 mod 12321

And finally I want to do (2^1000003 - 3) mod 12321. Is there any feasible way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic modulo properties tell us that

1) `a + b (mod n)` is `(a (mod n)) + (b (mod n)) (mod n)`, so you can split the operation in two steps

2) `a * b (mod n)`  is `(a (mod n)) * (b (mod n)) (mod n)`, so you can use modulo exponentiation (pseudocode):

```
x = 1
for (10000003 times) {
    x = (x * 2) % 12321; # x will never grow beyond 12320
}
```

Of course, you shouldn't do 10000003 iterations, just remember that 2<sup>1000003</sup> = 2 * 2<sup>1000002</sup> , and 2<sup>1000002</sup> = (2<sup>500001</sup>)<sup>2</sup> and so on...

Answer (score 3):

In some reasonably C- or java-like language:

```
def modPow(Long base, Long exponent, Long modulus) = {
  if (exponent < 0) {complain or throw or whatever}
  else if (exponent == 0) {
    return 1;
  } else if (exponent & 1 == 1) { // odd exponent
    return (base * modPow(base, exponent - 1, modulus)) % modulus;
  } else {
    Long halfexp = modPow(base, exponent / 2, modulus);
    return (halfexp * halfexp) % modulus;
  }
}
```

This requires that `modulus` is small enough that both `(modulus - 1) * (modulus - 1)` and `base * (modulus - 1)` won't overflow whatever integer type you're using. If `modulus` is too large for that, then there are some other techniques to compensate a bit, but it's probably just easier to attack it with some arbitrary-precision integer arithmetic library.

Then, what you want is:

```
(modPow(2, 1000003, 12321) + (12321 - 3)) % 12321
```

Comment: Or use some built-in function like `java.math.BigInteger.modPow` that uses this same logic.

Answer (score -1):

Well in Java there's an easy way to do this:

```
Math.pow(2, 1000003) % 12321;
```

For languages without the `Math.*` functions built in it'd be a little harder. Can you clarify which language this is supposed to be in?

Comment: `Math.pow(2, 1000003)` that'll just plain overflow.

Comment: I'm playing around with the Ackermann in Lisp but this need not be in Lisp at all. In fact this causes overflow error.

Comment: Math.pow(2, 1000003) evaluates to "Infinity".. then when you mod it, you get a NaN.

Comment: @peppe true, didnt even think about that.

Comment: The function you're looking for is `BigInteger.modPow`, as in:

     `(new BigInteger("2")).modPow(new BigInteger("1000003"), new BigInteger("12321"));`

Comment: @DanielMartin Is the Java BigInteger powerful enough to compute  (2^1000003 - 3) mod 12321 ?

Comment: Yes; just ran that line in beanshell. (Answer is 4610 before you subtract 3. Presumably you can subtract 3 yourself.)