# Sum of large exponents of 2

Tags: c++, algorithm, algebra

I am trying to complete a coding challenge from [hackerrank.com](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/shashank-and-list)

> Shashank is a newbie to mathematics, and he is very excited after knowing that a given l of cardinality N has (2<sup>N</sup> - 1) non-empty sublist. He writes down all the non-empty sublists for a given set A. For each sublist, he calculates sublist_sum, which is the sum of elements and denotes them by S<sub>1</sub>, S<sub>2</sub>, S<sub>3</sub>, ... , S<sub>(2<sup>N</sup>-1)</sub>.
>
> He then defines a special_sum, P.
>
> P = 2<sup>S<sub>1</sub></sup> + 2<sup>S<sub>2</sub></sup> + 2<sup>S<sub>3</sub></sup> .... + 2<sup>S<sub>(2<sup>N</sup>-1)</sub></sup> and reports P % (10^9 + 7).
>
> **OUPUT** Print special_sum, P modulo (10^9 + 7).

I am near certain I have misunderstood the prompt, but my program is meant to receive a list of numbers. The program will raise 2 to the power of all combinations of this list (without duplicates, order doesn't matter, of all sizes), then sum them all together and print it.

The example from the website is

> **List** `1, 1, 2`
> **Ouput** `44`
>
> **Explanation**
>
> 1. {1} and 2^1 = 2
> 2. {1} and 2^1 = 2
> 3. {2} and 2^2 = 4
> 4. {1,1} and 2^2 = 4
> 5. {1,2} and 2^3 = 8
> 6. {1,2} and 2^3 = 8
> 7. {1,1,2} and 2^4 = 16
>
> So the total will be 44;

My understanding of merely summing the exponents together is wrong because the answer is much larger than the expected answer in the first test case (obviously).

> **Input** `422 412 417 497 284` **Output** 67920854

Essentially, I want someone to explain the prompt. I think I'm just calculating the partial sum, but I don't know when or what I'm suppose to `mod 10^9 + 7`.

FYI I've only completed Algebra II, so if I've missed a mathematical concept, then keep my experience in mind when you explain it to me. I've been programming in C++, so code examples in the language is preferred.

**Code** My pitiful attempt at a solution: http://pastebin.com/c7YxCLMt

Comment: "explain the prompt." What? I can assure you that 2 to the 422th power will be much, much, larger than 67920854. The first part of this question is fairly legible; but halfway through it kind of falls off the cliff... And completely ommiting the [mcve] isn't helpful, either.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't really know where to turn. My problem is conceptional, so my source code is useless. I'll add the full prompt

Comment: Unfortunately, stackoverflow.com is not for discussion of conceptual problems. But, rather, for specific technical questions and answers.

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: Part of the challenge is figuring out how to understand the problem. `2^422` is a ridiculously large number. You cannot calculate it using simple operations. So the challenge is to see if you can figure out how to 'restructure the maths' so you can provide a simple computational solution. _It wouldn't be your challenge if someone else solves it for you. ;)_

Comment: Modulo of sum is sum of modulos. (4 + 4) mod 3 = 2 = 4 mod 3 + 4 mod 3. So you have only know how to compute modulo from 2^N mod XXX, and sum later, and that is an easy problem

Comment: mn... interesting problem. Perhaps this will help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem if 10^9 + 7 is actually a prime number, then maybe you could somehow simplify your list of sublists. If the original list can have up to 10^5 elements, it's a fool's errand to generate all sublists.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your attempt, it's hard to say what might be the flaw but two things come to mind as possible pitfalls:

1. You mention that you are supposed to `mod 10^9 + 7` but make sure you are doing `mod (10^9 + 7)`
2. The numbers you are calculating (2^497, 2^284, etc.) are *enormous* and would certainly overflow.  If you are not handling this already, you might be able to improve your attempt by trying something like what they are doing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177781/how-to-calculate-modulus-of-large-numbers).

**Edit:** After looking over your code, it does appear that you are running into the overflow problem.  You will benefit from incorporating the ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410389/how-to-calculate-the-mod-of-large-exponents) into your solution.

Answer (score 2):

The question is essentially: given a list of numbers, find the sum of all possible products of 1 or more of the elements, where the list is not the list you're given but two to those powers. Your example is the sum of the products of one or more of {2, 2, 4}, for example.

We can simplify this further by looking at the sum of the products of 0 or more of the elements, and then subtracting 1 for the empty product we didn't want. This lets you use a neat trick: for each element in the list, you will either multiply by 1 or by the number. So with the list {2, 2, 4} the sum is (2+1)(2+1)(4+1) = 3*3*5 = 45, giving 45 - 1 = 44 as the answer.

---

Here's some working code in PARI/GP.

```
specialSum(v, m=10^9+7)=lift(factorback(apply(n -> Mod(2,m)^n+1, v))-1)
```

Usage:

```
specialSum([1,1,2])
specialSum([422,412,417,497,284])
```

Comment: Does this work for the other set of numbers in the question? `422 412 417 497 284`?

Comment: @smac89 Yes it does. Remember to raise those numbers to the power of two first as described in my first paragraph.

Comment: @MyLoneTrojan As simple as possible: For each number n compute 2 to the power of n plus one. Multiply all these numbers together and subtract 1.

Comment: @MyLoneTrojan But probably you'll need to know how to compute modular addition, multiplication, and exponentiation first. If not you'll have huge numbers to work with, and that is probably even more effort.

Comment: so ... 2^N mod (10^9 + 7) + 1 for each number?

Comment: @MyLoneTrojan Yes. Then add 1 to each, then multiply them all (mod 10^9+7), then subtract 1.

Comment: @MyLoneTrojan I added some code (terse) to show that the idea works for both the example and the actual question. It runs in a fraction of a second.

Comment: How did you know how to simplify? can you link to some theorem or proof?

Comment: @MyLoneTrojan My post is a proof -- I haven't seen this before, I just worked it out now.

Comment: I don't understand why you're adding and subtracting by one

Comment: @MyLoneTrojan Adding 1 is including or not including each factor. If you expand (2+1)(2+1)(4+1) you'll get 8 products, and you're trying to get the sum of all of them except the smallest, which is 1. Subtracting 1 gets rid of that. See my second paragraph.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120939/discussion-between-mylone-trojan-and-charles).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments above, I think you are not quite familiar of these algorithmic online judges. They are not the same with real life applications, they normally have extreme constrains which force you to use some clever tricks to handle it in time. (usually ~1 second)

---

For this question, the problem can be separated into two parts:

1. How to sum `N^2`  integers in time when `N <= 10^5`? (in 1 second)
2. How to calculate `2^x % M` where `x <= 10^5*10^10 = 10^15` in time? (in 1 second)

And of course, in the process, you cannot make any variable overflow, which is the reason why the problem asks you to output answer MOD 10^9 + 7 *(I assume you know the basic properties of modular arithmetic.)*

For point 1, the answer is, **you can't.** What I am trying to imply is that, **there is some way that you can calculate the answer without summing N^2 items**. I can give you a hints based on my accepted solution: ***Dynamic Programming***, let DP(N) = required sum for items in array[0..N]. If you can formulate the DP recurrence, you can get the answer by summing only **N** integers, which can be calculated in time.

For point 2, you cannot do any naive linear pre-computation (use a for loop and times two of previous iteration, etc). By using DP mentioned in above, you only need to calculate `2^x % M where x <= 10^10`, still the memory and the run time constrain will fail if you do that. Here you need another trick called [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) which can compute `2^n` in `O(lg n)`, and thus acceptable.

---

Combine both point 1 & 2, you can solve this problem by **Dynamic Programming** & **Exponentiation by squaring** (& some basic modular arithmetic in between).